# Swift - passing game score to second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I'm trying to pass the highscore from my `GameScene` to my `GameOverViewController`.  I've successfully added the segue `GameOver` and the app works as expected.

The point of the `GameOVerViewController` is to display the score, advert and replay option.

I've looked at a number of tutorials however I seem to be hitting a wall.  Here is my current set up.

`GameScene.swift` contains the game code

`ViewController` contains tracking and banner ads

`GameOverViewController` displays advert, replay and hopefully the score soon.

`GameOver` name of the segue that links the two views

`scoreLabelNode.text = "Score \(score)"` displays score on `GameScene`

On my `GameOVerViewController` I've added a label where I would like to show the score as so...

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

var recevedString: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        Label.text = recevedString
```

On my `GameScene` I've tried the following function

```
func segue(){

    self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOver", sender: viewController)
    var secondViewController: GameOverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as GameOverViewController

    secondViewController.recevedString = scoreLabelNode.text
}
```

no this correctly points out the following error that `() -> () does not have a member named destinationViewController'`

Would anyone know the correct code to help send the high score data or point me in the right direction if I've gone wrong.

Thank you.

---

### UPDATED CODE

Would anyone know why the score still isn't pulling through to my `GameOVerViewController` after I've made the changes?  I'm guessing something is missing from `didBeginContact to call the`prepareForSegue`.  Thank you.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if( moving.speed > 0 ) {

        if((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory) == scoreCategory || (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask & scoreCategory) == scoreCategory){

            score++
            scoreLabelNode.text = "Score \(score)"
        }else {

            moving.speed = 0;

//lots of game over code removed from here

            return segue()
        }

    }

}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "GameOver")
    {
        let destVC = (segue.destinationViewController as? GameOverViewController)!
        destVC.recevedString = scoreLabelNode.text
    }
}

func segue(){
    self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOver", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `prepareForSegue` I guess.
Try this :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "GameOver")
        {
            let destVC = (segue.destinationViewController as? GameOverViewController)!
            destVC.recevedString = scoreLabelNode.text
        }
 }
```

and now your `segue()` will look like

```
func segue(){
    self.viewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOver", sender: self)
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've added the function as you recommended but my code doesn't appear to take any notice of `prepare for segue`.  Do you know what i need to add to my `didBeginContact`?

Comment: @RichTownsend Has `segue()` been called? Did you check it?

Comment: I only call for `segue` in my `didBeginContat` I'm not too sure why it still isn't working, I've updated my code above.

Comment: Try this: replace `return segue()` line with `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GameOver", sender: self)` You will come to know whether segue works or not

Comment: when i replace `return segue()` I get `gameScene does not have identifier named 'performSegueWithIdentifier'`any ideas?